# JavaScript: is it faster to cache deeply nested variables?

Tags: javascript, performance

Let's say I have a variable nested deeply within a massive object which I re-use quite often:

```
i = 10000000;
while (i) {
    i--;
    document.write( bigobject.a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h.i.j.k.l.m.n.o.p );
}
```

Would it be faster to cache it in a new variable outside of the loop?

```
v = bigobject.a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h.i.j.k.l.m.n.o.p
```

and use that cached variable in my loop?

```
document.write ( v );
```

For the less visually oriented: **Are JavaScript variables cached automatically or does the browser have to search through the larger variable each time it's requested?**

Comment: most are cached, but if there's a getter in the path, like is common with the DOM and expandos, everything to the right has to be re-gathered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As with all performance questions of importance, it is always best to test your specific situation in a tool like jsperf.com so you can measure the exact situation you care about and you should also run the test in multiple browsers to make sure what you're measuring is a general characteristic of the language implementation, not just a peculiarity to one browser.

In answer to your question, it is generally faster to cache a deep object reference if you are going to be accessing it multiple times.

In the specific example, I coded here: http://jsperf.com/cache-deep-reference, the cached reference was more than 2x faster in chrome and more than 4x faster in IE10.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/cachedeepprops, i added it. No big perf gain. But my loops are small.

Comment: in fact even for multiple accesses, there is no big gain in performance, when compared with cached one.

Comment: @TamilVendhan - that's why my answer states that each performance issue of consequence must be measured.  I measured the particular example the OP used and it does make a measurable difference.  Other situations may have different outcomes.  In your particular case, `console.log()` is a bad thing to use in a performance testing loop because it's quite slow and can easily mask what you are actually trying to measure.

Comment: I am just sharing my observations & opinions :-) I accept your view & I know its right, when it comes for performance.

Comment: Yes, `console.log` is really a bad thing. Once i removed it, things become faster & the results are now completely different.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is already answered however, I just made my own test for this and thought that someone on SO may find it useful:

```
ClassCreate('app').props.set('cipher', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'z']);

perfTest({
    ns: 'noCache',
    fn: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            console.log(app.props.get('cipher'));
        }
    }
});

perfTest({
    ns: 'cached',
    fn: function() {
        var cipher = app.props.get('cipher');
        for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            console.log(cipher);
        }
    }
});
```

**RESULTS**

**Cached variable x500: 812.261ms**

**Direct access to object in same x500 loop: 1050.416ms**