# When to use const keyword for variable vs when to traverse the object

Tags: javascript, performance, javascript-objects

I am working on a JavaScript application where I have to access a big object at many places. I am wondering what is the better way to go for it in terms of time and space optimisation.
For example, let's say I have on object (this is just an example, my objects will be much bigger and deeply nested):

```
family: {
    person: {
        firstName: Sherlock,
        lastName: Holmes,
        age: 22,
        address: {
            building: 221B,
            addressLine1: Baker Street,
            city: London,
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if I want to access the address here and print it on my webpage, then what is the good approach:

Shall I do this:

```
<div>{family.person.address.building}</div>
<div>{family.person.address.addressLine1}</div>
<div>{family.person.address.city}</div>
```

or, I store them in consts and then display here like:

```
const address = family.person.address
const {
    building, addressLine1, city
} = address
<div>{building}</div>
<div>{addressLine1}</div>
<div>{city}</div>
```

In the former one, I am not creating new variable but traversing the object in depth each time I have to access something.

In the latter one, I don't have to do that traverse but have created 4 new variables

**I feel second one is the fast approach (takes less time) because object is not traversed multiple times but I didn't find any articles supporting it.**

Which approach will give me better time or space optimisation in my application?

Comment: Both approaches are okay. However you should think about whether introducing more variables into the current scope is worth it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: is it faster to cache deeply nested variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376811/javascript-is-it-faster-to-cache-deeply-nested-variables)